# Can switches have multiple labels?

Tags: material-ui

I need to have a on/off switch in my program. After looking into the documentation i could not find a way to add multiple labels to a single switch

I need to have something like this in material-ui:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the Grid component from material-ui to create a custom Switch. To have both texts before and after your switch as Grid items. It would look something like this:

```
<Grid component="label" container alignItems="center" spacing={1}>
      <Grid item>Off</Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Switch
          checked={state.checked} // relevant state for your case
          onChange={handleChange} // relevant method to handle your change
          value="checked" // some value you need
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>On</Grid>
</Grid>
```

Here is a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-d4cj6) to a sandbox for your case.

Answer (score 1):

When using the new version of Material UI, you can use a Stack to create a double labeled switch.

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import Switch from "@mui/material/Switch";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

export const Page = () => {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false);

  const toggleCollapsed = useCallback(() => {
    setCollapsed(previouslyCollapsed => {
      return !previouslyCollapsed;
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Stack direction="row" component="label" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
      <Typography>
        Off
      </Typography>
      <Switch onChange={toggleCollapsed} value={collapsed} />
      <Typography>
        On
      </Typography>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```